# Mascaramento para campo data

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Quem já usou o `type="date"` do HTML5 certamente notou que, apesar da data estar visível no formato **DD/MM/YYYY**, quando você recupera o *value* pelo JavaScript, ela está no formato **YYYY-MM-DD**.

O que eu quero é justamente reproduzir esse mesmo efeito. O usuário vê a informação no formato X, escreve no formato X, mas na verdade está no formato Y.

Alguém saberia me dizer como é possível fazer esse tipo de mascaramento <strike>(se é que é possível)</strike>? Ou pelo menos aonde eu posso encontrar algum material relevante a minha duvida?
Eu estou procurando em outros fóruns e no <strike>lord</strike> Google, mas tudo o que eu encontro são as formatações costumeiras de como passar de um formato para o outro.

Sei que tem a turma do "para que fazer se já tem pronto", mas a minha proposta é aprender. Eu gostei do efeito criado e, se for possível reproduzi-lo, eu gostaria de saber como.

---

**-- EDIT --**
O efeito que eu estou tentando criar é esse aqui:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O que faço no meu caso é: Recebo a data no javascript no formato *YYYY-MM-DD* e converto para *DD/MM/YYYY*. É isso que queres fazer?

Comment: @CesarMiguel Não. O que eu estou querendo é reproduzir o mesmo efeito criado pelo `type="date"` do HTML5. Para o usuário a data estará no formato _DD/MM/YYYY_ mas, para o código ela estará no formato _YYYY-MM-DD_.

Comment: Você quer que visualmente seja YYYY/MM/DD ?

Comment: @Fúlvio Não. Visualmente estará no formato _DD/MM/YYYY_, mas no código estará no formato _YYYY-MM-DD_.

Comment: Desculpa eu não entendi sua duvida

Comment: @JúlioPradera, não te esqueças que o atributo `date` só funciona no chrome. Entretanto, enganei me a responder, o que estou a fazer no javascript é receber no formato `DD/MM/YYYY` e converto para `YYYY-MM-DD` e envio para o controller

Comment: @Fúlvio Coloquei uma imagem para ilustrar a minha duvida.

Answer (score 2):

Bem, no HTML5 desde que o elemento tenha uma ID, esse elemento será armazenado em uma variável cujo identificado é a ID que foi definida no HTML. Então dentro de uma propriedade desse input você pode definir o texto que você quiser a partir de um evento.

No exemplo abaixo eu fiz assim: toda vez que o usuário digitar uma letra, ele pega o conteúdo da textbox, faz o tratamento que eu quero, e adiciona o texto tratado na propriedade hiddenValue da própria textbox, depois quando me for conveniente, eu recupero o valor desse modo.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>HTML Element as var</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <input id="username" value="" placeholder="hamboldt" onkeyup="getText(this);"/>
        <button onclick="alert(username.hiddenValue);">Ver valor escondido.</button>
    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getText(input) {
            input.hiddenValue = input.value + "hidden";
        }
    </script>

</html>
```

Comment: Não é exatamente o que eu estou procurando. Para tal, eu continuaria tendo que formatar a data no momento do carregamento da página. Mas a proposta é bem interessante. Me será útil em um "problema" que eu estou tendo. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Júlio, se é esse o efeito que você está procurando é possível também adicionar uma função a ser chamada no `onload` para processar o valor do *input* e gerar o `hiddenValue`.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly Já havia pensando nisso, mas depois me ocorreu que o campo pode ser alterado dinamicamente. Assim, toda vez que o campo for alterado de forma dinâmica, será preciso chama uma função para fazer isso. Caso eu consiga reproduzir o efeito desejado, pretendo adiciona-lo a minha biblioteca, utilizada aqui no trabalho. Então, chamar uma função toda vez que for alterar o valor do campo, pode ser meio chato.

Comment: Você pode usar o [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) para tratar esse tipo de mudança. Mas Júlio, de verdade, sentindo o que você quer fazer eu realmente vou ter que concordar com sua autocrítica e dizer para não reinventar a roda. Essas soluções começam a ficar ineficientes e trazer todo tipo de problema de *cross-browser* rapidamente. Além do que uma hora você vai perceber que esse é um subproblema do problema real (binding entre view e modelo), um problema bem resolvido por bibliotecas como Knockout e AngularJS.